# How to compare a dictionary and string and output a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python and trying to write code which can compare a dictionary with a string. My input dictionary and string looks like this:

```
l = {'Python' : 'high-level language', 'PHP' : 'ssl', 'Java' : 'low-level language'}

st = 'Python and Php and Java are programming languages. PYTHON and PHP and JAVA are good skills to have. python and php and java are programming languages'
```

I want to do a case insensitive comparison between the dictionary keys and string individual words (applying split function on string) and output the following:

```
final_output = {'Python' : 'high-level language',
     'and' : 'O',
     'Php' : 'ssl',
     'anbd' : 'O',
     'Java' : 'low-level language',
     'are' : 'O',
     'programming' : 'O',
     'languages.' : 'O',
     'PYTHON' : 'high-level language',
     'and' : 'O',
     'PHP' : 'ssl',
     'and' : 'O',
     'JAVA' : 'low-level language',
     'are' : 'O',
     'good' : 'O',
     'skills' : 'O',
     'to' : 'O',
     'have.' : 'O',
     'python' : 'high-level language',
     'and' : 'O',
     'php' : 'ssl',
     'and' : 'O',
     'java' : 'low-level language',
     'are' : 'O',
     'programming' : 'O',
     'languages' : 'O'}
```

or like list of tuples where the integrity of the sentence would be maintained (which is also important in my case)

```
    final_output = [('Python' , 'low-level language'),
 ('and' , 'O'),
 ('Php' , 'ssl'),
 ('and' , 'O'),
 ('Java' , 'low-level language'),
 ('are' , 'O'),
 ('programming' , 'O'),
 ('languages.' , 'O'),
 ('PYTHON' , 'high-level language'),
 ('and' , 'O'),
 ('PHP' , 'ssl'),
 ('and' , 'O'),
 ('JAVA' , 'low-level language'),
 ('are' , 'O'),
 ('good' , 'O'),
 ('skills' , 'O'),
 ('to' , 'O'),
 ('have.' , 'O'),
 ('python' , 'high-level language'),
 ('and' , 'O'),
 ('php' , 'ssl'),
 ('and' , 'O'),
 ('java' , 'low-level language'),
 ('are' , 'O'),
 ('programming' , 'O'),
 ('languages' , 'O')]
```

I tried to achieve this by considering my inputs to compare as two lists (rather than comparison between dictionary of keys and string) and wrote the following line of code:

```
l = ['Python', 'PHP', 'Java']

st = 'Python and Php and Java are programming languages. PYTHON and PHP and JAVA are good skills to have. python and php and java are programming languages'
```

For the above input I wrote:

```
[i for i in (st.split(' ')) if i.lower() in [i.lower() for i in l]]
```

and got the output as:

```
['Python', 'Php', 'Java', 'PYTHON', 'PHP', 'JAVA', 'python', 'php', 'java']
```

I want to apply this to compare dictionary and list and get the output as required, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: `I want to ....` Did you do anything? Where's your code?

Comment: Sorry... I updated my question with what I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so simple:

```
l = {'Python' : 'high-level language', 'PHP' : 'ssl', 'Java' : 'low-level language'}
st = 'Python and Php and Java are programming languages. PYTHON and PHP and JAVA are good skills to have. python and php and java are programming languages'
l2 = {k.upper():v for k, v in l.items()}
output_dict = {i:l2.get(i.upper(), 'O') for i in st.split(' ')}
```

Output will be:

```
 {'JAVA': 'low-level language',
'Java': 'low-level language',
 'PHP': 'ssl',
 'PYTHON': 'high-level language',
 'Php': 'ssl',
 'Python': 'high-level language',
 'and': 'O',
 'are': 'O',
 'good': 'O',
 'have.': 'O',
 'java': 'low-level language',
 'languages': 'O',
 'languages.': 'O',
 'php': 'ssl',
 'programming': 'O',
 'python': 'high-level language',
 'skills': 'O',
 'to': 'O'}
```

If you want to get the same order with you input! just simple do it by a order key!:

```
your_order_key = 'Python and Php and Java are programming languages. PYTHON and PHP and JAVA are good skills to have. python and php and java are programming languages'.split(' ')
```

to get a order dict! you can use `collection lib`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

order_dict = OrderedDict()
for k in your_order_key:
    order_dict[k]=output.get(k)
```

Put it all :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
order_dict = OrderedDict()

l = {'Python' : 'high-level language', 'PHP' : 'ssl', 'Java' : 'low-level language'}
st = 'Python and Php and Java are programming languages. PYTHON and PHP and JAVA are good skills to have. python and php and java are programming languages'
l2 = {k.upper():v for k, v in l.items()}
output_dict = {i:l2.get(i.upper(), 'O') for i in st.split(' ')}
for k in your_order_key:
    order_dict[k]=output.get(k)
```

And then you output will be:

```
OrderedDict([('Python', 'high-level language'),
             ('and', 'O'),
             ('Php', 'ssl'),
             ('Java', 'low-level language'),
             ('are', 'O'),
             ('programming', 'O'),
             ('languages.', 'O'),
             ('PYTHON', 'high-level language'),
             ('PHP', 'ssl'),
             ('JAVA', 'low-level language'),
             ('good', 'O'),
             ('skills', 'O'),
             ('to', 'O'),
             ('have.', 'O'),
             ('python', 'high-level language'),
             ('php', 'ssl'),
             ('java', 'low-level language'),
             ('languages', 'O')])
```

Comment: You forgot the case insensitivity requirement.

Comment: The integrity of the sentences should be maintained (I know that we can't maintain the order of keys in dictionary (like I mentioned in my expected output). But any help in outputting the result as list of tuples would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't use two loops for this simple task, just use logic and some
>   conditions instead of many loops and your work can be done in just one
>   loop :

```
import json

data_keys = {'Python': 'high-level language', 'PHP': 'ssl', 'Java': 'low-level language'}

data = 'Python and Php and Java are programming languages. PYTHON and PHP and JAVA are good skills to have. python and php and java are programming languages'

result = {}
for words in data.split():

    if words.title() in data_keys:
        result[words] = data_keys.get(words.title())
    elif words.lower() in data_keys:
        result[words] = data_keys.get(words.lower())
    elif words.upper() in data_keys:
        result[words] = data_keys.get(words.upper())



    else:
        result[words] = 0

print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

> output:

```
{
  "php": "ssl",
  "Java": "low-level language",
  "Python": "high-level language",
  "to": 0,
  "programming": 0,
  "have.": 0,
  "java": "low-level language",
  "PHP": "ssl",
  "languages": 0,
  "python": "high-level language",
  "skills": 0,
  "languages.": 0,
  "Php": "ssl",
  "JAVA": "low-level language",
  "are": 0,
  "PYTHON": "high-level language",
  "and": 0,
  "good": 0
}
```

If you want to maintain the order as you commented out:

> The integrity of the sentences should be maintained

Then:

```
import json

data_keys = {'Python': 'high-level language', 'PHP': 'ssl', 'Java': 'low-level language'}

data = 'Python and Php and Java are programming languages. PYTHON and PHP and JAVA are good skills to have. python and php and java are programming languages'

result = []
for words in data.split():

    if words.title() in data_keys:
        result.append((words,data_keys.get(words.title())))
    elif words.lower() in data_keys:
        result.append((words,data_keys.get(words.lower())))
    elif words.upper() in data_keys:
        result.append((words,data_keys.get(words.upper())))




    else:
        result.append((words,0))



print(json.dumps(result,indent=2))
```

output:

```
[
  [
    "Python",
    "high-level language"
  ],
  [
    "and",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Php",
    "ssl"
  ],
  [
    "and",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Java",
    "low-level language"
  ],
  [
    "are",
    0
  ],
  [
    "programming",
    0
  ],
  [
    "languages.",
    0
  ],
  [
    "PYTHON",
    "high-level language"
  ],
  [
    "and",
    0
  ],
  [
    "PHP",
    "ssl"
  ],
  [
    "and",
    0
  ],
  [
    "JAVA",
    "low-level language"
  ],
  [
    "are",
    0
  ],
  [
    "good",
    0
  ],
  [
    "skills",
    0
  ],
  [
    "to",
    0
  ],
  [
    "have.",
    0
  ],
  [
    "python",
    "high-level language"
  ],
  [
    "and",
    0
  ],
  [
    "php",
    "ssl"
  ],
  [
    "and",
    0
  ],
  [
    "java",
    "low-level language"
  ],
  [
    "are",
    0
  ],
  [
    "programming",
    0
  ],
  [
    "languages",
    0
  ]
]
```